# Vuejs3: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'title')

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am learning  vuejs language and I would like to create a tabs component and I followed a tutorial that allowed me to create a simple one and now I would like to customize it. For example I would like to not necessarily have to put the title of the table. I tried to put a default value to the title property but when I map the slots table I get an error because it does not find the title.
In TabsComponent we have:

```
 <template>
  <div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tabs_header">
      <li
        v-for="title in tabTitles"
        :key="title"
        @click="actualTitle = title"
        :class="{ actual: title === actualTitle }"
      >
        {{ title }}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, provide } from "vue";
export default {
  name: "TabsComponents",
  setup(props, { slots }) {
    const tabTitles = ref(slots.default().map((tab) => tab.props.title));   
    const actualTitle = ref(tabTitles.value[0]);

    provide("actualTitle", actualTitle);
    return { actualTitle, tabTitles };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.tabs {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tabs_header {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.tabs_header li {
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s all ease-out;
}

.tabs_header li.actual {
  background-color: darkorange;
  color: black;
}
</style>
```

And in TabComponent we have:

```
<template>
  <div class="tab-content" v-show="title == actualTitle" :title="title">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { inject } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "TabComponent",
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: "Tab",
    },
  },
  setup() {
    const actualTitle = inject("actualTitle");
    return {
      actualTitle,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.tab-content {
  min-height: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
</style>
```

This is the App.vue :

```
<template>
  <TabsComponent>
    <TabComponent> I'm first Tab </TabComponent>
    <TabComponent title="Second"> I'm second Tab </TabComponent>
    <TabComponent title="Disabled"> I'm disabled Tab </TabComponent>
  </TabsComponent>
</template>

<script>
import TabsComponent from "./components/TabsComponent.vue";
import TabComponent from "./components/TabComponent.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    TabComponent,
    TabsComponent,
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

My error is here when I do `<TabComponent> I'm first Tab </TabComponent>` I have an error on this line `const tabTitles = ref(slots.default().map((tab) => tab.props.title));` in TabsComponents file. And I don't understand because I thought the default value in TabComponent file would be taken.

Comment: I don't think so. You are accessing the slots of the `TabsComponent`. The default value is set within the scope of the `TabComponent`, after resolving the prop value as `undefined`. For my understanding, why are you trying to get the titles from the slots? That seems a rather complex way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I must admit that I don't know how to retrieve the list of titles otherwise any advice to give me?

Comment: Since you now are defining the tab titles in the app.vue, you could also create an tabsTitles array like: `const tabTitles = ['', 'Second', 'Disabled']` and then bind these to the TabComponent like `<TabComponent :title="tabTitles[0]">` and the full array to the TabsComponent as `<TabsComponents :tabTitles="tabTitles">`.  You need to define tabTitles as a prop in TabsComponent.